# Dataflow Streaming Job Error: name 'function' is not defined. How to create a global function for all Dataflow steps

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, worker, global-scope, global-functions

I'm developing a Dataflow streaming job for CSV check triggered by a creation of an object in Cloud Storage (via Pub\Sub notification).

I'm using Dataflow because is a business requirement and for the message de-duplication management (could be possible with Pub\Sub).

In each pipeline step I make a particularry type of control (the check rules are defined in a Google Sheet that I read with a step that I've created in the pipeline).
If all steps are ok, copy the file in onother bucket, otherwise send an email of error. For these reason I need a global function to call possibly in all steps.

I've declaired the function afer the library invokation:

```
from email import header
from hashlib import new
from msilib.schema import Error
import json
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import pvalue, window, GroupByKey
from datetime import datetime

import logging, uuid

from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions

TOPIC = "TOPIC_PATH"

def test():
    # send an email
    print("Send email")


class ReadPubSubMessage(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        self.prod_bucket = "prd-v2"
        self.invalid_bucket = "prd-error"

    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        import uuid, json
        from datetime import datetime

        # Creating a uuid for the ingested file identification 
        try:
            uuidOne = uuid.uuid1()
            logging.info("Reading PubSub message")

            # Reading the PubSub json end extracting main information
            res = json.loads(element)
            path_loaded_blob = res["id"]
            type_object = res["contentType"]
            
            # Getting the date from the blob path
            list_of_path_parts = path_loaded_blob.split("/")
            
            . # other code
            .
            .

            yield final_list
        except Exception as e:
            test(email)
            logging.error("Error: " + str(e))


beam_options = PipelineOptions()
google_cloud_options = beam_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
    
    check_csv = (pipeline 
        | "ReadData" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=TOPIC) # Ok 
        | "Decode" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')) # Ok 
        | "Extract informations from PubSub message" >> beam.ParDo(ReadPubSubMessage()) # Ok 
        .
        .
        .
        | beam.Map(lambda x:logging.info(x))
    )
```

The error that i receive is:

`NameError: name 'external_functions' is not defined`

I think it's because workers have not the code scope but only the task code.

How can i write a global function in a Streaming Job Dataflow? Or share a basic example using a global function in more tasks in Dataflow?

Thank you for the time

I create a little snippet of code for simulate the situation. I've create another python file containing a function that i call (after making an import of the lib) but i've the same error.

I've tried also to define the function inside the main but obviously doesn't work.

main.py below

```
import apache_beam as beam

import logging
# import library_list as external_functions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions

# class stepGeneral(beam.DoFn):
#     def process(self, element):
#         variable = "External function"
#         logging.info("Called general method")
#         yield variable

TOPIC = "TOPIC NAME"

class step1(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        variable = "first"
        logging.info("This is the " + variable + " step")
        yield variable

class step2(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        variable = "second"
        logging.info("This is the " + variable + " step")
        # stepGeneral.process()
        external_functions.stepGeneral()
        yield variable

beam_options = PipelineOptions()
google_cloud_options = beam_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
    
    (pipeline
        | "ReadData" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=TOPIC) # Ok 
        | "First step" >> beam.ParDo(step1())
        | "Second step" >> beam.ParDo(step2())
        # | "window" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(1)) 
        | beam.Map(lambda x:logging.info(x))
    )
```

And below the library_list.py

```
import logging

def stepGeneral():
    variable = "External function"
    logging.info("Called general method")
    yield variable
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/ for how to ship and manage pipeline dependencies for your Python code. You could consider using cloudpickle which may resolve some issues as well (see https://beam.apache.org/blog/beam-2.36.0/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had already seen the first page linked and I suppose that I've to create my own library to call with the instruction linked. Is it so?
The second link can be usefull, those are features I didn't know about. Helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

As your code starts growing beyond one-single-file (i.e. adding classes), you need to pay more attention into the building and submitting the container.

Pretty much you need to start building your own custom container (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers) that inherits from the python+apachebeam container you want, meaning that your Dockerfile will have to start with:

FROM apache/beam_python_sdk:

i.e. FROM apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.38.0

When using custom containers, you need to re-run the gcloud builds command to every time you add a new file, to ensure your file makes it into the container.

gcloud --project my-google-project builds submit -t THEIMAGE . --timeout 20m
*THEIMAGE is the image location to use in gcr.io.   (you can provide a config.yaml file instead of the longer command as in the satellites tutorial)

The satellites tutorial is, in my opinion, quite illustrative of the whole process: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/tutorials/satellite-images-gpus

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).